# Can we keep our customer's X509 Certificate as BLOB on our server?

Tags: certificates

I have a scenario in which I need to use the customer's X509 certificate and passphrase for executing their web services.

Now, I need to know what will it be a security breach if I store customers' X509 certificate on my server as a BLOB and use it.

If it is a security breach than what is the best approach to use that certificate.

Comment: Is this a server certificate or a client certificate? Why is the service provider issuing you a certificate? Normally, you'd create your own key, you generate a CSR, and then let the service provider or a CA sign your CSR into a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: On second thought, this seems to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info).

**Iff** you store the **certificate**, that isn't a problem as that is just a veryfied public key, i.e. public information.

I do however suspect that you do not mean *certificate* since you also seem to need a password.

If you do indeed mean the private key: you should not keep it; you shouldn't have it to keep in the first place. If you do need to do things on behalf of a client, ask them to provide you with reasonable means of access for whatever service you need to run for them.

One might suspect that you do mean *private key for an https certificate*. Yes, if you are the hoster, you do need the private key for the https certificate - and it's not a personal certificate of the client, it rather just demonstrates control over the IP or domain - which you have as a hoster.

Since you seem confused about basic terminology, I'd advise you to not store any customer data and instead focus on understanding what you're trying to do first.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi for the reply, actually it is clients personal certificate which he/she sends with the Rest APIs. They use our Web Service client and hence we also need to send it with Rest APIs, in this case we will be needing their certificate.

Comment: Like I said, it seems to be an XY Problem. You're doing it wrong (tm) if you need their certificate and provisioning your own is no option. However, you're giving way too little information on the process to determine what you're doing wrong. Also, that would be off-topic here and more a software design question.